# canvas.coords not updating all entries

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to make a "fish tank" in Python, which uses a canvas in Tkinter. In it, I need fish which can be spawned by pressing a button and which move in the direction dx, dy where both dx and dy are random values between -3 and 3 generated for each spawned fish. Once they approach the edge of the tank, they should bounce in the opposite direction (like the DVD screensavers).

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import time
import random
from Tkinter import *

tank = Tk()
tank.title("Fish Tank")

tankwidth = 700 # (the background image is 700 by 525)
tankheight = 525
x = tankwidth/2
y = tankheight/2
fishwidth = 78 # (the fish image is 78 by 92)
fishheight = 92
fishx = fishwidth/2
fishy = fishheight/2
dx = 0
dy = 0

canvas     = Canvas(tank,width=tankwidth,height=tankheight)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
bg         = PhotoImage(file = "tank.gif")
left       = PhotoImage(file = "fishleft.gif")
right      = PhotoImage(file = "fishright.gif")
background = canvas.create_image(x,y,image=bg)
rightfish = canvas.create_image(-1234,-1234, image=right)
leftfish = canvas.create_image(-1234,-1234, image=left)

def newfish():
    x = random.randrange(fishx+5, tankwidth-(fishx+5))   # +5 here so even the biggest dx or dy
    y = random.randrange(fishy+5, tankheight-(fishy+5))  # won't get stuck between the border
    dx = random.randrange(-3,4)
    dy = random.randrange(-3,4)
    leftfish = canvas.create_image(x,y, image=left)
    rightfish = canvas.create_image(-1234,-1234, image=right)
    updatefish(leftfish,rightfish,x,y,dx,dy)

def updatefish(left,right,x,y,dx,dy):
    x += dx
    y += dy
    if dx < 0:
        whichfish = left
        canvas.coords(right,-1234,-1234)
    if dx > 0:
        whichfish = right
        canvas.coords(left,-1234,-1234)    
    if x < fishx or x > tankwidth-fishx:
        dx = -dx
    if y < fishy or y > tankheight-fishy:
        dy = -dy
    print x, y, dx, dy
    canvas.coords(whichfish, x,y)
    canvas.after(100, updatefish, leftfish,rightfish,x,y,dx,dy)

newfish()

new = Button(tank, text="Add Another Fish", command=newfish)
new.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="NS")
tank.mainloop()
```

I think the problem is here:

```
rightfish = canvas.create_image(-1234,-1234, image=right)
leftfish = canvas.create_image(-1234,-1234, image=left)
```

With it, when I spawn a fish, one instance of the fish will stay where it was spawned and a second will move as it's supposed to. Without it, I get "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'whichfish' referenced before assignment" or errors complaining about leftfish or rightfish not existing, even though they have been spawned and appear in newfish() before they're used in updatefish(). So, I can spawn fish, but they won't move.

This is minor league compared to a lot of the stuff on here but any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'whichfish' referenced before assignment` problem is occurring because `dx` and `dy` are allowed to have the value `0`, but you only assign a value to `whichfish` if `dx` and `dy` are nonzero.

One way to fix this:  Replace the `randrange` statements with these:

```
dx = random.choice([-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3])
dy = random.choice([-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3])
```

As to why you're getting fish that don't move:
You're assigning the *images* for the left and right fish to `whichfish`, then you're using `whichfish` as the *canvas ID* for the fish.  Try this instead:

```
whichfish = leftfish
```

instead of

```
whichfish = left
```

and similarly for `rightfish`.  There are some other problems you're going to run into, but that's the most immediate one.